# Сериализация объекта в Android

Tags: java, android

Пишу игру под Android. Стоит задача каким-то образом хранить данные. Так как вся игровая логика у меня представлена в виде одного сложного объекта GameModel, я решил, что сериализация объекта в фаил - это то что мне нужно. Но я не знаю как сделать это на Android. В этом и вопрос.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118751/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-and-save-it-to-a-file-in-android

Comment: Хоаните данные в базе

Answer (score 0):

Вот хороший [пример](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-write-java-object-to-a-file) с конвертацией класса в Serializable и затем запись в файл

Но стоит учитывать, что сериализовать весь файл со всей игровой логикой может быть плохой идеей. Serializable очень медленный. При загрузке и сохранении большого числа объектов он использует много памяти. Это может фатально сказаться на играбельности